# Map<Type1, Type2> not defined in WebMIDI typings, not clear where to get definition of Map

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm fairly new to Typescript and typings.  I'm using Visual Studio Code and hoping to get good auto-completion for the WebMIDI interface (a javasccript API available in some browsers).

I installed the webmidi typings like this:

```
D:\Mike\Dev\WebMIDI\WebMidiTest>typings install --global dt~webmidi
webmidi
`-- (No dependencies)
```

After installing, Visual Studio Code still doesn't seem to understand all of the types involved.  When i actually view the index.d.ts file for webmidi, i noticed that there are red underlines underneath usages of the `Map` and `Promise` classes.

I was able to get Visual Studio Code to know what a map was by installing the "es6-collections" typings package.  I tried also doing `typings install dt~promise` which installed some definitions of `Promise` however Visual Studio Code still doesn't seem to understand the usage of `Promise` contained in the WebMIDI definition file.

Is it a bug with the WebMIDI typings that they don't properly specify the dependencies?  Should typings packages which rely on other typings packages automatically install them when you do `typings install`?  Or is there something else that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use the `typings` tool anymore. Just do `npm install --save-dev @types/webmidi`. TypeScript will identify your types inside `@types` folder.

Comment: I see.   It seems like just yesterday that read an article saying that the typings tool was the latest and greatest way of getting typings.  Hard to keep track, but with regards to dependencies, npm seems like it would work better.  However, if I do ```npm install --save @types/webmidi``` I still have the same problem where the Map<X,Y> is not defined and Visual Studio Code underlines it.   Also tried ```npm install --save-dev @ryancavanaugh/webmidi``` but then VSC did not even recognize the "WebMidi" identifier.  It was not clear why because it was defined in a .d.ts file that npm installed.

Comment: That is because `Map<X,Y>` is not part of the `webmidi` definition. It is part of es6 standard. Can you try adding `"lib": ["es6"]` to your `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: I realize that Map is not in webmidi.  Question is 1) whether webmidi's type defs should be considered buggy by not specifying the dependency on another type definition package, and 2) where the "correct" place to find the definition of Map is.    I found that ```npm install --save @types/es6-collections``` satisfied the dependency, but it's not clear whether this is the "correct" way.  I tried your suggestion of ```lib: es6``` (without es6-collections). This resolved Map as well, but then many other identifiers are undefined, e.g. EventTarget, Event, etc. and not clear where to get them.